# Vue bind element data to html property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want to bind selected rows to an array, i'm trying to bind data from a v-for to the value of my input. 
I tried v-bind:value="row.id", i tried value={{row.id}} but nothing seems to be working.

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="row in get_rows()">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="row.id" v-model="selectedRows">
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Post more of your code, I can't reproduce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/rq8d5uyv/

Answer (score 1):

In order for your code to work you need to make sure you initialize `selectedRows` as an array. Add this to your component:

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedRows: []
  }
},
```